# iphone: integrate java code with xcode project

Tags: java, iphone, ipad

Please enlighten me on this,
is it possible to execute code written in java or play with classes written in java from xcode project for iphone/ipad.
while googling I got thi
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040321163154226 but I guess this solution is not working and is deprecated on mac platforms as well.
Just to highlight I see

Regards
Ankit

Comment: There is no good way to get Java code to run on iOS (unless you consider jail-breaking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible, since there is no Java virtual machine available for iOS.